# CLLocationCoordinate2D to MKMapPoint using PROJ4

Tags: mkmapview, map-projections, wgs84, proj

I am attempting to use the Proj4 library to transform different map projections for use with Apple Map Kit.  For testing purposes I thought I would start with duplicating the MKMapPointForCoordinate function using Proj4.

These are the definitions I am using:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

When I use the coordinate 47.5, -97.3 the Proj4 transformation returns:

6028687.013553943, -10834169.44145535

But MKMapPointForCoordinate returns:
61646948.12444445, 93835627.5941129 which is an order of magnitude off.

The world size for Map Kit is 268435456 x 268435456

Comment: Why not just use the latitude and longitude from proj4 as-is in MapKit instead of converting to MKMapPoint?

Comment: I am trying to understand the correct settings for Proj4 and the test above was the easiest way I knew to verify the results I get from Proj4 and MKMapPointForCoordinate are the same.  My actual problem is more difficult then this so I wanted to start with a simple/basic problem first. I for instance can not even understand where you are able to specify the range of cartesian coordinates using Proj4 since it appears Google Map and MapKit have different ranges.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your goal.

Answer (score 0):

With the following definitions:

+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +nadgrids=@null +no_defs

+proj=merc    +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=134217728.0 +y_0=134217728.0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 + k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs

there is one more step to close the gap between Mapkit and Proj4: 
a linear regression in x and
a linear regression in y.

```
let const_x = 114180219.657211
let a1_x    = -0.850708929130513

private func mk_x_forProjX(projX: Double) -> Double {
    return (projX - self.const_x) / (self.a1_x + 1)
}

private func proj_x_forMKX(mkX: Double) -> Double {
    return mkX * (self.a1_x + 1) + self.const_x
}

let const_y = 154255236.342789
let a1_y    = -1.14929107086948

private func mk_y_forProjY(projY: Double) -> Double {
    return (projY - self.const_y) / (self.a1_y + 1)
}

private func proj_y_forMKY(mkY: Double) -> Double {
    return mkY * (self.a1_y + 1) + self.const_y
}
```

The fit is not perfect, but the precision is satisfying enough.

One last point,
be sure to use Double when converting degrees <-> radians, 
i.e :

```
static func DegreesToRadians (value:Double) -> Double {
    return value * M_PI / 180.0
}

static func RadiansToDegrees (value:Double) -> Double {
    return value * 180.0 / M_PI
}
```